# Facebook app links broken

Tags: facebook, authentication, hyperlink

Today, on my Facebook app, links appear to be broken. Everytime you click a link (to another page of the application, not external), Facebook returns the user to the login prompt, even if the user has already logged in.. I usually use relative urls, but if I set absolute, the link doesn't work too, but in this case the page doesn't change...
Anyone having same problems? Any ideas? I just can't find solutions..

Edit: for "Facebook app" I mean an iframe application that runs on Facebook site, not the Facebook application for a mobile device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved :) The problem was I used on old versione of the PHP SDK. I've updated the SDK with the latest version and also the Login part of the code; now it's ok. Thanks all for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to reinstall the Facebook app? Also if you use Android you can delete the cache on your phone.

Comment: Perphaps i explained it wrong.. I mean an iframe application that runs on Facebook site :) I just edited the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Everytime you click a link (to another page of the application, not external), Facebook returns the user to the login prompt, even if the user has already logged in..

Do you have Authenticated Referrals turned on for your app?

Otherwise, you must be triggering login yourself somewhere in your app. If so, check the conditions under which you are doing so, and if your app recognizes a logged in user correctly, or if maybe there is some kind of cookie problem.

If that doesn’t help you to figure it out on your own, please update your question with relevant code.